# Cmd not capturing username in python

Tags: python, automation

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import subprocess


config = subprocess.check_output(["openvpn","credentials.ovpn"])

if config == ("Enter Auth Username:"):
    subprocess.call("Ru6cEvx6bx")
```

Hi guys, just making very small script to connect to openvpn. Where i don’t have to put username and password every-time to connect to the vpn.

Comment: Every time you call subprocess, it's in a new terminal -- so your previous commands will not be stored in the session

Comment: Any solution? Im new to coding. Thanks

Comment: Look into paramiko